# Find the absolute path of linux default application

Tags: linux

I'd like to **find the absolute path of linux default application**.

i found this : /etc/gnome/defaults.list

but they don't give the absolute path of these application. :(

thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `locate` command,

```
locate libreoffice-calc.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the name of the program, you can get its absolute path with `which PROGRAM`, e.g. `which ps`

Answer (score -1):

but there are a problem. for example, if you do :

"cat /etc/gnome/defaults.list"

you have this :

...
text/csv=libreoffice-calc.desktop
...

and i'd like to found where is located "libreoffice-calc".
it doesn't work if i type this which libreoffice-calc

Comment: I suspect this was meant to be a comment